# Select only specific element

Tags: ruby, rhomobile

I have an array:

```
line = ["0;\t0\n", "1;\t0\n", "2;\t0\n", "3;\t0\n", "4;\t0\n", "5;\t0\n", "6;\t0\n", "7;\t0\n", "8;\t0\n", "9;\t0\n", "10;\t0\n", "11;\t0\n", "12;\t0\n", "13;\t0\n", "14;\t0\n", "15;\t0\n", "16;\t0\n", "17;\t0\n", "18;\t0\n", "19;\t0\n", "20;\t0\n", "21;\t4,8\n", "22;\t9,5\n", "23;\t13,8\n", "24;\t18,5"]
```

I want to extract the values behind the semicolon. Is it possible to extract the values (0, 0, 0, ..., 4, 8, 9, 5, 13, 6 etc.)? How can I do it? I tried:

```
sa=line.split(";")
sa1=sa[1].delete "\n"
sa1=sa1.delete "\t"
sa1=sa1.to_i
$sa1 = sa1
```

When I display `$sa1`, I only see `18,5`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's easy:

```
str = ["0;\t0\n", "1;\t0\n", "2;\t0\n", "3;\t0\n", "4;\t0\n", "5;\t0\n", "6;\t0\n", "7;\t0\n", "8;\t0\n", "9;\t0\n", "10;\t0\n", "11;\t0\n", "12;\t0\n", "13;\t0\n", "14;\t0\n", "15;\t0\n", "16;\t0\n", "17;\t0\n", "18;\t0\n", "19;\t0\n", "20;\t0\n", "21;\t4,8\n", "22;\t9,5\n", "23;\t13,8\n", "24;\t18,5"]

p str.map{|el| el.split(/;\t/)[1].chomp}
```

Result:

```
# ["0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "4,8", "9,5", "13,8", "18,5"]
```

Comment: @user2610581 you wrote *I want only the value behind the semicolon.*,instead I think you should write *I want only the value after the semicolon.*.... :)) lollz

Comment: @Priti desired result is `(0,0,0,...,4,8,9,5,13,6 etc.)` ;)

Comment: @YevgeniyAnfilofyev I covered the both.. *before* and *after*.. No worry... :))

Answer (score 0):

```
a=["0;\t0\n", "1;\t0\n", "2;\t0\n"]
p a.map{|i| i[0..i.index(';')-1]}
#>> ["0", "1", "2"]

a=["0;\t0\n", "1;\t0\n", "2;\t12\n"]
p a.map{|i| i[i.index("\t")+1..-1].chomp}
# >> ["0", "0", "12"]
```

Answer (score 0):

`Sting#[]`

```
line.map{|s| s[/;\s*(\S+)/, 1]}
# => ["0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "4,8", "9,5", "13,8", "18,5"]
```